# What is a maximal number factored by Shor's algorithm so far?

Tags: shors-algorithm

With reference to a similar question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2111/what-integers-have-been-factored-with-shors-algorithm), I would like to know what is the maximal number which has been factored with Shor's algorithm so far on actual quantum hardware.

The reason I am asking a similar question as the link is that this question is from 2018 and I would expect that some progress has taken place since that time, especially in light of introducing a 65 qubits processor by IBM.

I also saw some other techniques for factoring integers to primes but these are based on converting the factorization problem to QUBO instead of period finding as in the case of Shor's algorithm:

- [Quantum factorization of 56153 with only 4 qubits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.6758)
- [Variational Quantum Factoring](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.08927)

These algorithms are able to factor integers in an order of ten or a hundred thousand but according to my knowledge, Shor's algorithm has been demonstrated on very simple cases like factoring 15, 21, and 35.

I also found *adapted* Shor's algorithm described in [An Experimental Study of Shor's Factoring Algorithm on IBM Q](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00768), which should provide better performance on processors with a limited (small) number of qubits. However, again only numbers 15, 21, and 35 were factored in.

I would appreciate it if anyone can me provide a link to the paper(s) discussing progress in Shor's algorithm implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it is worth, here is a paper by Craig Gidney on [how to factor 2048 bit RSA integers in 8 hours using 20 million noisy qubits.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.09749v2.pdf)
Hopefully others will be able to add more related papers.

Correct me if I am wrong but I don't think those other algorithms like the Variational Quantum Factoring actually offers any advantage over classical algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for the paper. Yes, you are right that the advantage on Variational Algorithm or others based on QUBO is not very significant, or at least we are currently not sure how big the advantage  is. It seems that solving QUBO problems on gate-based quantum computer or quantum annealer is better only in constant and the complexity is still exponential. However, this is still under investigation.

Answer (score 4):

None of the current implementations of Shor’s algorithm could actually be said to factor. These implementations used information about the factorization to factor (i.e, a known element of small order). Here’s [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.7007.pdf) that explains and expands the ‘compiled’ version of Shor’s algorithm.

Comment: A couple years after the paper that you mentioned, 15 was factored again and this time without prior knowledge of the factor, but they used a semi-classical QFT which requires long coherence times.

Comment: Could you please reference that paper. I think there must be some confusion as, according to a [2021 paper](https://europepmc.org/article/pmc/pmc8368060), in the ‘Compiled Shor’s algorithm’ section, it would take ‘9000 elementary quantum gates acting on 26 qubits’. Compiled versions of Shor’s algorithm take advantage of known order(s) — which is essentially knowledge of the factors.

Comment: Anna, you can look at my SE network profile, then look at the highest voted question that I asked on Theoretical Computer Science SE. If you're going to upvote Peter Shor's answer, please do not do it blindly just because it's by Shor. Some people told me that they did that and can't change their vote now even though they want to. What's swept under the rug in the paper and Shor's answer is that coherence times will have to be much longer, to implement Shor's algorithm in the way that they did. However they didn't assume knowledge of the factors. I'm on a phone so can't send you the paper.

Comment: user1271772: If you can type that much on your phone, you can copy and paste a link to a paper. Compiled versions of Shor’s algorithm use fixed elements with known, very small orders - most commonly order 2 where the element is not -1 modulo N. This is, with a little elementary number theory, pre-knowledge of the factors.

Comment: **You do not get to decide what people do here.**

Comment: Iterating a qubit fewer times in the iterating version of Shor's algorithm is the same as reducing the number of qubits in the original Shor's algorithm. It's related to the accuracy. Reducing qubits or fewer recycling are the problem of the current quantum devices which leads to the compilation of the algorithm using prior knowledge. That means the previous Shor's algorithm demos are not genuine demo. See the paper https://www.nature.com/articles/nature12290 for more details about the compilation. And the importance of the paper that used recycling version is the usage of modular multipliers.