# A concrete 4-qubit circuit that computes $ a^j \mod{15}$?

Tags: modular-exponentiation, period-finding-algorithm

As a [follow up](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32892/how-does-the-v-gate-perform-modular-exponentiation) to a previous question on period finding and factoring, could anyone give a real construction of a 4-qubit circuit that can output (in the same 4-qubit binary format)

$$ a^j \mod{15}$$

for any free choice of $a$ and $j = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14\}$, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing the [Circuit for Shor’s algorithm using 2n+3 qubits](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205095) I had to use a function like this. You can check out my full implementation of this algorithm [here](https://github.com/epelaaez/QuantumLibrary/blob/master/papers/Shor%E2%80%99s%20using%202n%2B3%20qubits.ipynb).

You can construct this by first defining a gate that performs addition as follows:

```python
def adder(n, val_a, dag=False):
    """
    Construct gate to add val_a into register b in the Fourier basis.
    Register b must contain the number on the Fourier basis already.
    The subtracter gate gives us b - a if b ≥ a or 2^{n+1}−(a−b) if b < a.
    The subtracter is obtained by inversing the adder.
    
    Parameters:
    -----------
    n: QuantumRegister
        Size of register b
    val_a: int
        Value to which register a will be initialized
    dag: Boolean
        If set to true, the dagger of the adder gate (the subtracter) is appended
    
    Returns:
    --------
    adder_gate: Gate
        Constructed gate
    """
    
    bin_a = "{0:b}".format(val_a).zfill(n)
    phase = lambda lam: np.array([[1, 0], [0, np.exp(1j * lam)]])
    identity = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
    arr_gates = []
    
    for i in range(n):
        qubit_gate = identity
        for j in range(i, n):
            if bin_a[j] == '1':
                qubit_gate = phase(np.pi / (2 ** (j - i))) @ qubit_gate
        arr_gates.append(qubit_gate)

    unitary = arr_gates[0]
    for i in range(1, len(arr_gates)):
        unitary = np.kron(arr_gates[i], unitary)
    
    adder_gate = UnitaryGate(unitary)
    adder_gate.label = f"Add {val_a}"
    if dag == True:
        adder_gate = adder_gate.inverse()
        adder_gate.label = f"Subtract {val_a}"
        
    return adder_gate
```

With this, you can construct a gate that computes $(a + b) \mod N$. So for your case just set $b = 0$ and define $a := a^j$ as you wish. This gate can be defined as follows:

```python
def mod_adder(n, val_a, val_N):
    """
    Construct gate to compute a + b mod N in the Fourier basis. 
    Register b must contain the number on the Fourier basis already.
    The answer will be in this register.
    
    Parameters:
    -----------
    n: QuantumRegister
        Size of register b
    val_a: int
        Value to add to register
    val_N: int
        We take mod of a + b respect to this value
        
    Returns:
    --------
    mod_adder_gate: Gate
        Constructed gate
        
    """ 
    
    reg_c = QuantumRegister(2)
    reg_b = QuantumRegister(n)
    aux   = QuantumRegister(1)
    gate  = QuantumCircuit(reg_c, reg_b, aux)
    
    qft     = QFT(n, name="$QFT$").to_gate()
    qft_inv = QFT(n, inverse=True, name="$QFT^\dag$").to_gate()
    
    gate.append(adder(n, val_a).control(2), reg_c[:] + reg_b[:])
    gate.append(adder(n, val_N, dag=True), reg_b[:])
    
    gate.append(qft_inv, reg_b[:])
    gate.cx(reg_b[-1], aux[0])
    gate.append(qft, reg_b[:])
    
    gate.append(adder(n, val_N).control(1), aux[:] + reg_b[:])
    gate.append(adder(n, val_a, dag=True).control(2), reg_c[:] + reg_b[:])
    
    gate.append(qft_inv, reg_b[:])
    gate.x(reg_b[-1])
    gate.cx(reg_b[-1], aux[0])
    gate.x(reg_b[-1])
    gate.append(qft, reg_b[:])
    
    gate.append(adder(n, val_a).control(2), reg_c[:] + reg_b[:])
    mod_adder_gate = gate.to_gate(label=f"Add {val_a} mod {val_N}")
    
    return mod_adder_gate
```

For more details on this, you can read the notebook I linked.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, may I ask what's the equivalence of exponential $a^j \mod{N}$ in Fourier basis? I think your code is implying that addition $(a+b) \mod{N}$ in Fourier basis is the same as exponentiation $a^j \mod{N}$ in normal basis? I can roughly see $\omega^j$ somewhere, but cannot quite fathom the exact relation between Fourier basis and normal basis...

Comment: My code transforms the input into the Fourier basis, performs the addition, and then transforms back into normal basis. So, at the end, you end up in the normal basis.

Comment: Also, consider accepting answers to your questions if they solve your doubt!

Comment: sorry was away for a while. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There seems no simple general-purpose circuit that can output

$$ a^j \mod{N}$$

for arbitrarily free choice of $a, j, N$.

For instance,

[image]

(from https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-95973-w)

uses a very specific circuit that outputs a hard-coded

$$ 4^j \mod{21}$$

while already [pre-knowing that the period](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14340/what-is-a-maximal-number-factored-by-shors-algorithm-so-far) is 3; thus it is pre-known that a 2 qubit modulo-container register is enough to handle the output period of:

$$4^0 = 1 \mod{21}$$
$$4^1 = 4 \mod{21}$$
$$4^2 = 16 \mod{21}$$
$$4^3 = 1 \mod{21}$$

The three residues are further encoded into 2-bit modulo containers as

$$ 1 \mod{21} \rightarrow |11\rangle$$
$$ 4 \mod{21} \rightarrow |10\rangle$$
$$ 16 \mod{21} \rightarrow |01\rangle$$

only approximately correctly as a waveform:

[image]

The final probability spike is not completely clean either:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thus, the main difficulty in factoring seems to be in implementing an all-purpose circuit for outputing

$$a^j \mod{N}$$

rather than the Fourier transform, which is composed of just $H, P(\theta)$, or the phase estimation.